# XML file parsing - Get data from a child of a child

Tags: python, xml, parsing, python-3.x

I know how to get data from a child tag but I would like to get data from a child tag of a child tag of the "root" tag.
We can use this database for example :

```
<DB>
    <Entry>
        <Name></Name>
        <DisplayName>Assembly.iam</DisplayName>
        <Scalar>
          <Name>d0</Name>
          <DisplayName>d0 (value = 0 mm)</DisplayName>
          <Value>0</Value>
        </Scalar>
    </Entry>
</DB>
```

Here is my code to get data from just a child tag :

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.parse("C:\\Users\\Vince\\test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
for entry in root.findall('Entry'):
    name = entry.find('DisplayName').text
    print(name)
```

It outputs : `Assembly.iam`

But now, how can I display `d0 (value = 0 mm)` ?

Comment: Do you mean to print every `<DisplayName>` values?

Comment: Yes but I have already printed the `<DisplayName></DisplayName>` which is inside `<Entry></Entry>`. Also, I would like to print `<DisplayName></DisplayName>` which is inside `<Scalar></Scalar>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For printing all display names , You should try -

```
dnames = entry.findall(".//DisplayName")
for x in dnames:
    print(x.text)
```

For getting the specific display name under `<Scalar>` , you can do the below-

```
name = entry.find('./Scalar/DisplayName').text
print(name)
```

Comment: It gives following error: `SyntaxError: cannot use absolute path on element`. It works using current context, like: `entry.findall(".//DisplayName")`. The same for second part.